# How do I select a long part of a complicated expression between two symbols inserted for the purpose?

Tags: string-manipulation

I want to select a long expression that spills over into many pages. Using mouse and cursor makes it go really fast. Is there a way I can insert some characters and instruct Mathematica to pick up only the portion in between the characters?

Specifically imagine I want to select the portion between ZZ and ZZ without unnecessarily counting the number of characters in the string fragment to be extracted.

Original string :

akerkjer3jr3r4b3brk3ZZrb34krbf3kfnef3erefZZvmexckdijo3rj3rf3erferfe3r3f

Output : rb34krbf3kfnef3eref

Comment: Yes. Please delete that question. I am unable to do it.

Comment: `StringCases[str, 
 StartOfString ~~ __ ~~ "ZZ" ~~ h___ ~~ "ZZ" ~~ k__ ~~ EndOfString :> 
  h]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = "akerkjer3jr3r4b3brk3ZZrb34krbf3kfnef3erefZZvmexckdijo3rj3rf3erferfe3r3f"
r = StringCases[s, "Z" ~~ x___ ~~ "Z" -> x]
StringReplace[r, "Z" -> ""]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]